# How to authenticate multiple objects in Cakephp 3?

Tags: authentication, cakephp-3.0

In a Cakephp 3 aplication, i have users table and members table, i want the application to be able to authenticate users and members, can u share with me a way to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe you should try the tutorial about authentication first. http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/blog-auth-example/auth.html

Comment: Thanks @AlexStallen, i already did authentication using a single model (User or another model), now im trying to authenticate with two or more models.

Comment: is that needed? you can give users different roles and by those roles different access

Comment: Thanks @AlexStallen, thats the point, im doing that now.